# ios: Switching from custom layout to flow layout in uicollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am building a collectionView using swift language in xcode 7.3 . I have to support both custom layout and flow layout . For this purpose I have added 2 buttons to choose the layout .

When I am in custom layout i wanna change the layout to flow layout by clicking on a button. When I do this I get the item size to be the default value (50,50).

I wanna change the itemSize to (100,100) and I also wanna know how to set the center(x,y) values for each item in flow layout . I want the items to be fixed in a particular position .

Any suggestions, help would be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: implement the methods in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` will do all.

Comment: I am implementing - collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath: and - collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex: for setting the item size and item spacing inside a separate flowlayout class. But the changes are not visible on the view . Its still using the default value.

Comment: Have you set your view controller as the collection view's delegate?

Comment: How do i do that ? Is it inside viewDidLoad() of viewcontroller ?   Sorry if i am asking basic questions. I am new to ios and swift .. Thanks

Comment: yes, in the viewDidLoad method.  `self.collectionView.delegate = self`

Comment: Actually I have created a separate file for flow layout . I have a button in my view . When i press that button it goes to that file and implements code . I am not implementing flow layout code in that viewController class itself . I hope you are getting me .

Comment: @MudOnTire Thanks for the suggestion . I am now implementing flow layout delegate in view controller . I have set itemSize and itemSpacing successfully . But the items are not placed in proper positions in the view . Some of the cells are not visible now . I think the problem is in the x & y position of each item . How to set those values ?

Comment: As i know there is no way to set the items' x & y, you can only set `minimumLineSpacing`, `minimumInteritemSpacing`, `itemSize`, `sectionInset`. Why are some cells invisible? can you scroll the collection view?

Comment: Yes scrolling is possible . But the first item is not starting from 0,0 position in flow layout. Initial few items are invisible .  I am implementing circular and semi circular layout as well. These 2 are custom layout . I have created buttons to switch to flow,circular or semi circular layout .   When i goto circular or semi circular layout and then switch to flow layout, some items are missing from the screen .. Help !!

Comment: can you show your code implementing the collection view dataSource, delegate.

Comment: Hello. I changed the anchor point of the frame to (0.5,0.5). This solved my problem .   Previously the anchor point of frame was in another co ordinate[like (-0.8,-0.8)])  and hence some cells were not visible . For different layout there is different anchor point .    @MudOnTire Thanks for the help. As you said the problem is not with (x,y) point but it was with anchor point of frame .

Comment: You're welcome and congratulations, i didn't help much, all your own efforts.

Comment: Thank you . But i had to know that (x,y) point cannot be changed . Thanks for that .